# ArcGIS online - how to display a label show below 1:100

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online

I'm trying to show cemetery label plots at all scales.  I have tried to change the visible range within the label features (see screenshot below) but this wont let me go below 1:100.  Anything that I type in below 100 will default back to 100.

The problem is that our cremation plots are approx 30cm x 30cm so even at a 1:100 scale these 3mm squares are too small to view labels (three digit numbers).

How do I allow labels to show below 1:100?
Is there an alternative way that would work?

[image: snapshot of label features]

**EDIT:**
I have allowed further zoom within the map settings of the application which allow for the map to zoom into 1:25 (yes the basemap will disappear at this level but that isn't a problem).  Hence why I should be able to see labels at this same scale.

[image: Map scale has been changed to allow for extra zoom]

Comment: Convert labels to annotations in arcgis, use feature outline to features and publish them

Comment: @FelixIP thanks, that was just what I needed.  Can you please write this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Convert labels to annotations in ArcGIS
- use [feature outline to mask tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/feature-outline-masks.htm) and publish output polygons.

This way you can see labels in Collector as well, not just ArcGIS online.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, 1:100 looks like the maximum scale you can zoom at.

So there is no point displaying the label scale at a finer level of detail, because there isn't. 1:100 is the maximum scale you can zoom at. That's probably why ArcGIS online won't let you do so.

See my screenshot, the zoom is 1 cm = 1 meters (or 100 cm, hence 1:100). And my labels are visible.

[image]

Comment: I have edited the map within the 'app' that allows for further zoom.  Yes this removes my basemap and only shows my poygons, but that is ideal in this situation.  I will add a picture of this into my question.  This still doesn't solve the labeling issue :/